# Enabling storage autoscaling in AWS RDS PostgreSQL can produces downtime?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, autoscaling, downtime

I want to enable storage autoscaling by the first time in a AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance.

Someone knows or have some documentation to clarify if this requires downtime? i can't found any articles or documentation about explicitly "enabling autoscaling by the first time"

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Amazon RDS now supports Storage Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/rds-storage-auto-scaling/):

> RDS Storage Auto Scaling automatically scales storage capacity in response to growing database workloads, **with zero downtime**.

The message you highlight suggests that downtime would only be caused by other changes in the "pending modifications queue" (eg a requested change of instance type).

Comment: Also the message is generic -- it only mentions what happens **"if"** any pending modifications require downtime.